# Entity Framework code first unique index for key and property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables, `Configuration` and `Device`. `Device` has a string property called `Name`. A configuration can have many devices. I want an index on the `Name` property, and the name must be unique within a configuration. So I want an index on multiple columns in the `Device` table, namely on `Configuration_ID` and `Name`.

```
class Configuration
{
    Guid ID { get; set; } 
    List<Device> Devices { get; set;
}

class Device
{
    Guid ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set;
}

class ConfigurationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Configuration>
{
    ConfigurationMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.HasMany(t => t.Devices).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}

class DeviceMap
{
    DeviceMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(t => t.DisplayName)
       .HasColumnName("Name")
       .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new            IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("NameIndex")))
       .HasMaxLength(450);
       // Where to put the other index?
    }
}
```

My two questions are:

- Is this a good idea at all? ;)
- How can I do that using fluent API?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ConfigurationId` property to `Device` class (foreign key). Then, in cofiguration, for both `ConfigurationId` and `Name` properties do:

```
Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IDX_ConfigurationId_Name", 0) { IsUnique = true }));
Property(t => t.ConfigurationId).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IDX_ConfigurationId_Name", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
```